# combinations of 3 values from an array

Tags: c#, arrays, boolean

```
var example = new[]{1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}
```

I want to produce an array of all arrays that have three 1s in combinations of places that this array does, and 0s in all other positions.

In this example, these will be:

```
1 1 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 1 0
1 1 0 0 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 1
0 1 1 0 1 0
0 1 1 0 0 1
0 1 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 0 1 1
```

Code I wrote to attempt this became extremely long and messy, there is obviously a better way.

I was trying using 'counters' that sat over positions of the original array, and moved like so:

```
1 1 1 0 1 1
c c c
c c     c
c c       c
c   c   c
```

etc...

Comment: Do you want someone to write it for you or did you have a specific question?

Comment: I'm guessing there should be a pretty basic way to do this with recursion. Will you only have 6 elements in the array normally?

Comment: Normally there will be many more elements in the array, and the array will be very sparse, with mostly 0s and a few 1s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array is relatively short (which it should be to avoid overflowing the memory) you could use binary counting to build and algorithm that you are looking for:

- Assume that the original array has `N` elements
- Convert the array to an `int` treating each position as a binary digit; call it `set`
- Make a `mask` number that counts in a loop from 0 to `(1 << N)-1`, inclusive. This mask produces all possible combinations of bits that can be taken from the original
- Produce a combination of `mask` and `set` by AND-ing the two: `int candidate = mask & set`
- Check how many bits are set in the `candidate`
- If the number of set bits is exactly three, add `candidate` to the list
- Once the loop is finished, you have your list represented as `int`s.
- Eliminate duplicates, and convert these `int`s to arrays of `int`s as necessary.

Here is a simple implementation of the above algorithm:

```
static uint FromArray(int[] data) {
    uint res = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i != data.Length ; i++) {
        if (data[i] == 1) {
            res |= (1U << i);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
static int[] ToArray(uint set, int size) {
    var res = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0 ; i != size ; i++) {
        if ((set & (1U << i)) != 0) {
            res[i] = 1;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
static int CountBits(uint set) {
    int res = 0;
    while (set != 0) {
        if ((set & 1) != 0) {
            res++;
        }
        set >>= 1;
    }
    return res;
}
public static void Main() {
    var example = new[]{1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1};
    var set = FromArray(example);
    int N = example.Length;
    var res = new List<uint>();
    for (uint mask = 0 ; mask != 1U<<N ; mask++) {
        var candidate = set & mask;
        if (CountBits(candidate) == 3) {
            res.Add(candidate);
        }
    }
    foreach (var s in res.Distinct()) {
        var array = ToArray(s, N);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", array.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray()));
    }
}
```

This code produces the following output:

```
1 1 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 1 0 1 0
1 1 0 0 0 1
1 0 1 0 0 1
0 1 1 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 1
0 1 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 0 1 1
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/0Yl3Yl)

Comment: @alan2here See `CountBits` above.